# Construct a matrix from a given data set and perform subsequent operations

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, data, dataset

I have data set, say, {${x_i, y_i}$} where $i$ varies from $1$ to $n$. Now, how can I construct the matrices

$M_i=\{\{1,x_i,x_i\},\{\ x_i,1,y_i\},\{x_i, y_i, 1 \}\}$

and perform the following operations ?

$\{V3_{i}, V2_{i}, V1_{i}\} = Eigenvectors[M_i]$

$R = Transpose[{V1_{i}, V2_{i}, V3_{i}}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much do as you already have.

```
Transpose@*Reverse@*Eigenvectors@*({{1, #1, #1}, {#1, 1, #2}, {#1, #2, 1}} &) @@@ data
```

For example with `data = (SeedRandom["Homotopy Theory is cool"]; RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];)`, the above gives (after a `Short[Chop@#, 2] &`)

> {{{0,0.83852,-0.544871},{-0.707107,-<<19>>,-<<19>>},{0.707107,-0.385282,-0.592923}},<<99>>}

Comment: I got my coffee this morning with non-dairy neutrinos. Tasted just as good, and there was no extra charge...